# R sapply in a for loop equivalent in Python

Tags: python, r, pandas

I have a code that I have to translate from R to python.
However I'm not very familiar with sapply equivalents in python.
This portion of code combines a for loop and sapply.

Here's the code:

```
for ( j in 1:nrow(df)) {
  train <- df$train_nbr[j]
  data <-  matrix(nrow= 1 ,ncol=length(num))
  colnames(data) <- num
  for ( i in  1:length(num)) {
    z <- num[i]
    data[,i] <- sapply(train ,function(y) ifelse(z!=y & substr(z,3,4) == substr(y ,3,4),FALSE, TRUE ))
    }
  data <- cbind(data, apply(data,1,function(y) sum(!y)))
  if( sum(data[,ncol(data)]) ) {
    error_1 <- paste(paste0("DL ",c(colnames(data)[which(data[1,]==0)])),sep="/")
    }
  else {
    error_1  <- "X" 
    }
```

The variable `num`, which is not defined in this code chunk is just a list of unique values of `df$train_nbr`

I think i can handle everything except the sapply inside the for loop containing variables from two loops...
Do you have an idea on how to do it with python/pandas?

Comment: the R code is very redundant.. and it looks like you have a list embedded in a data frame or tibble? can you provide an example of the input, otherwise your python code is not going to work.. i very doubt how well this R code work anyway

Answer (score 0):

The `sapply` is very similar to this code:

```
result <- logical()
for (k in seq_along(train))
  result[[k]] <- ifelse(z!=train[k] & substr(z,3,4) == substr(train[k] ,3,4),FALSE, TRUE ))
```

This is quite inefficient R code; it would probably be better to write it as

```
result <- z == train | substr(z, 3, 4) != substr(train, 3, 4)
```

but I think that's harder to translate to Python.

Comment: This is almost trivially translatable into Python - see my answer.

Comment: Shows how much Python I know!

Answer (score 0):

An efficient Python version, which is equivalent to the R version posted by user2554330, is

```py
    result = (df.train == df.z) | (df.train.str[2:4] != df.z.str[2:4])
```